# how to confirm email source

Tags: email

I send an email from my smtp server, for example, setting `From` to *anyemail@anydomain.com*. The recipient will think that email comes from `anydomain`. How to confirm the email source?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Generally, you don't really need to confirm the source. If they can read emails to that address, they own it. So that's all the confirmation you need to do (confirm they can read it).

Comment: some email i recieve through development and some i recieve from production although the development From is same as production. It is difficult which email came from which source.

Comment: So by "source" you mean "which deployment sent the email"?  In that case the content or headers of the email should have some characteristic that differs between deployment and production.  Are the SMTP servers different? Can you add your own content (e.g. X-Is-Development: True) or even just add some text in the body?

Comment: smtp server are different. can you give any example how to set headers in c#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several approaches to dealing with email forgery:

- Use [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) or [SSL signed certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smime)
- Use [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)
- check the `Received` headers (although this isn't reliable)
- reply back to the sender and ask if they actually sent it.  If you know the sender, maybe ask them in person or over the phone.

The main thing to realise is that the From: address isn't any form of guarantee about the originator of a message.

Edit: okay I now understand that you're just trying to tag the mail message somehow so that you can recognise which server generated it (in a non-secure way).  Here's how using .NET's MailMessage:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
msg.Headers.Add("X-Is-Development", "true");
```

Comment: smtp server are different. can you give any example how to set headers in c#

Comment: Received headers prove nothing? Need SSL/PGP or other pre-arranged token

Answer (score 1):

[Email Headers](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/header.html) has more details.